# qt qml : deploying sqlite database to android using .qrc file not working

Tags: android, c++, qt, sqlite, qml

I am trying to make an android application using qml and C++ on QtCreator and I am not able to deploy sqlite database to android :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QFile file(":/patients.db") ;
if (file.exists()) {
    file.copy("./patients.db") ;
    QFile::setPermissions("./patients.db",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner) ;
} else qDebug() << "the file does not exist" ;
db.setDatabaseName("./patients.db");
```

`patinets.db` exist under the qrc tree in QtCreator and the code work on my development host (Linux ubunntu)

But on android, the debug message "the file does not exist" gets printed out.

Am I missing something here?! What is the correct way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is helpfull if you check status return codes in each step of your 'deploying'. Both, `file.copy()` and `QFile::setPermissions()` have success indicating return values.

It is highly possibile, that already`file.copy("./patients.db")` failes, because on android you are not allowed to create any files in same directory where your binary/apk is contained.

You need to obtain the path to internal storage allocated for your app at runtime. [Link to 'Saving Files' of Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage). 
You should obtain the correct path by means of [`QStandartPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) (e.g. `AppLocalDataLocation`).

You could obtain a possible target directory and place your sqlite file there like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QFile file(":/patients.db") ;
QString patientDbPath;
if (file.exists()) {
    patientDbPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
    if (patientDbPath.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not obtain writable location.";
        return;
    }
    patientDbPath.append("/patients.db");
    file.copy(patientDbPath) ;
    QFile::setPermissions(patientDbPath ,QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner) ;
} else qDebug() << "the file does not exist" ;
db.setDatabaseName(patientDbPath);
```

Comment: `file.exists()` fails, so i don't reach the `copy()` and `setPermission()`